# How can I extract specified values from a string in excel document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have a column in excel that is linked to a table in Access. How can I extract certain values from the string when the values and location vary by row? I have a query linked to this table so I am hoping I can do this within Access but I also have some knowledge of PowerQuery.

Ex of existing strings:

12345_10_abc123.pdf

12345_6789_qqq.pdf

For the first string I would need to extract 10, for the second I would need qqq.

Comment: What is the criteria to determine the sub-string to extract ??

Comment: A list would contain the criteria so for this example it would be: 
10
qqq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `extract strings` are in a list someplace, you can use this formula:

```
B2: =INDEX(extrStrings, MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(extrStrings,A2)),0))
```

and fill down.

Depending on your version of Excel, since this is an array formula, you may need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

**List of Strings to Extract**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

The formula will only return a single keyword from the target. If you might have multiple keywords, and need to return them all, a different formula will be needed.

The formula will return an error if the keyword does not exist. If you want something else, just wrap the above formula in an `IFERROR` function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

This is one type of **keyword search**.  List the phrases in column **A** and the keywords in column **D**:

[image]

Our goal is to determine if a phrase contains a keyword.  If yes, put it in column **B**.  In **B1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$5,A1)),$D$1:$D$5,"")),$D$1:$E$5,1,FALSE),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not able to duplicate the above results. Should my columns have a certain format?

Comment: @christabelle  They should both be ***Text***...................also remember to ***array-enter*** the formulas.

Comment: Hmm, it is returning blank cells. Do you have any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: @christabelle it probably means there is an error that `IFERROR()` is hiding.  Remove the `IFERROR()` to see what the error is

Comment: @christabelle  Does your version of Excel support `JOINTEXT()` ??

Comment: Ahh no it does not. I am using Excel 2016 and apparently I need an Office 365 subscription.

Comment: @christabelle  If you want to experiment, the Excel web app has all the latest functions